# FTP client request failure

Tags: c++, ftp

I'm trying to develop an FTP protocol in c++. It takes the type of the request from the client as it is (get or put) however, the server always receives a put request in both cases and does none of the functionality.

Here the code that compare the type of the request:

```
if(strcmp(argv[3],"get")==0)
    smsg.type=REQ_GET; //REQ_TIME;
else if (strcmp(argv[3],"put")==0)
{
    smsg.type=REQ_PUT; //REQ_SIZE;

}
else err_sys("Wrong request type\n");
```

and this is the part that execute when a get request is sent to the server:

```
if(smsg.type=REQ_GET)
{
    cout<<"Iam inside get"<<endl;
    cout<<smsg.type<<endl;
    //send out GET message
    memcpy(smsg.buffer,&req,sizeof(req)); //copy the request to the msg's buffer
    smsg.length=sizeof(req);
    fprintf(stdout,"Send a GET request to %s\n",argv[1]);
    if (msg_send(sock,&smsg) != sizeof(req))
        err_sys("Sending req packet error.,exit");

    //receive the response
    if(msg_recv(sock,&rmsg)!=rmsg.length)
        err_sys("recv response error,exit");

    //cast it to the response structure
    respp=(Resp *)rmsg.buffer;
    printf("Response:%s\n\n\n",respp->response);}
```

when displaying "respp->response" it doesn't return anything, and always the size of the file is zero.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
- if(smsg.type=REQ_GET)
+ if(smsg.type==REQ_GET)
```

next time try to use -Wall when compiling, it might catch this kind of error